# Number of users of each group

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I need to generate a result set giving all the userGroup with the number of users in each group:

```
insert into groupUser value(1,"administrator");
insert into groupUser value(2,"commercial");
insert into groupUser value(3,"development");

insert into user value(1,"jack", 3);
insert into user value(2,"bill", 1);
insert into user value(3,"mark", 3);
```

the result should be :

```
administrator : 1
commercial : 0
development : 2
```

I could not find a solution.

Comment: You have to use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: what are the field names of both table.

Comment: whats the schema for these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you did not post table schemas...

```
select g.Name, count(u.usergroupId) as members
from groupUser g left join user u 
on  u.usergroupId = g.id
group by g.Name
```

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75e5d/3)

Comment: You should change tables in join `from groupUser g left join user u` because there are groups without users.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give u better result

```
Select GroupUser,[Count]

from   (Select groupid,count(*) 'Count' from user group by groupid) t

join    Groupuser G

on      G.id = t.id
```